# Check if KendoGrid selected checkbox is checked or not

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a [ASP.Net MVC Kendo Grid](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/checkbox-selection) with checkbox selection, as the documentation I added the checkbox using `columns.Select().Width(50);` as, then I want to fill an array of selected checkboxes inside of onChange function with javascript as:

Note: the stations array already have some values I.E [1,2,3], so I want to add new values in the next script

```js
function onChange(e) {
  const grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var items = grid.items();
  let ids = '';
  grid.select().each(function() {
    if (ids === '')
      ids = grid.dataItem(this).StationId.toString();
    else
      ids = ids + ',' + grid.dataItem(this).StationId.toString();
    stations.push(grid.dataItem(this).StationId);
  })
}
```

The problem is on each check it is adding all existing checked checkboxes, I have no way to do something like `if(checkbox is not checked)` do a pop instead a push.

How can I check if clicked checkbox is checked or not in order to implement push or pop logic?

Comment: made a snippet of your code to allow a quick format of it

Answer (score 0):

The select method will return all rows that are currently selected. If you need to figure out which is the checkbox that the user clicked last, you can [probably toggle a class when the checkbox is checked/unchecked](https://dojo.telerik.com/aNUCAWaV)

```
   function onChange(e) {
      const grid = e.sender;
      var items = grid.items();
      let ids = '';
      grid.select().each(function(idx,itm) {
        $(itm).find("input").hasClass("checkedFlag") ? 
          kendoConsole.log(grid.dataItem(itm).ProductName + " was checked") : 
          kendoConsole.log(grid.dataItem(itm).ProductName + " was NOT checked");
      })

      var selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
        return $(item).text();
      });

      kendoConsole.log("Selected: " + selected.length + " item(s), [" + selected.join(", ") + "]");
    }

    function onDataBound(arg) {
      $("input.k-select-checkbox").change(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("checkedFlag")
      })
      kendoConsole.log("Grid data bound");
    }
```

If you are interested in only the Id's of the selected items then the Grid exposes a [selectedKeyNames method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/selectedkeynames), that you could use instead.

Answer (score 0):

The change event of the Kendo grid will fire when the user selects or deselects a table row or cell in the grid ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/change)), but it does not provide us with which rows are selected or deselected.

What you will need to do is store the selected items outside of the grid, compare it to the results of the select method in the change event, then store the updated results.

Something along these lines:

```js
var selectedRecords = [];
function onChange(e) {
  var updatedSelectedRecords = e.sender.select();
  if (selectedRecords) {
    var recordsSelected = updatedSelectedRecords.filter(record => !selectedRecords.includes(record)).map(record => record.StationId.toString());
    stations.push(...recordsSelected);
    var recordsDeselected = selectedRecords.filter(record => !updatedSelectedRecords.includes(record));
    // do something with deselected records?
  }
  selectedRecords = updatedSelectedRecords;
}
```